# Ngrx Effects Calling API and Comparing with Store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

So I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days and I gave up, rxjs is very tricky specially when it comes to the `map` family.

I have an action `MessageRequested` with an `id` as the paramter, that should initiate an api call to get the Message, and then check whether the corresponding visitor is in the store or not. If it's not in the store it will dispatch two actions, `MessageLoaded` and `VisitorRequested`. If it's in the store, we will just dispatch one action, `MessageLoaded`. So logic would be in that order:

1. `MessageRequested` was dispatched with an `id` as the input
2. Now we call the api with `id` as the parameter, we have a `Message` object returned. Message definition below. It has a `visitor_id` property: `mergeMap((action) => this.converseService.getMessage( action[0].message_id ))`
3. Now we query the store, whether the `visitor_id` in the `Message` object exists in the Visitor state (`this.store.pipe(select(selectVisitorById( m.visitor_id ) )`)
4. Now we have an if condition we need to apply,

   a. if `select` returned something, then the visitor is already in the store, and we will return just the `MessageLoaded` action.

   b. If `select` didnt return a `visitor`, we now have to dispatch an additional action `VisitorRequested` to request the visitor. We still need to dispatch the `MessageLoaded` action. So thats 2 actions.

Now to the code:

```
    loadMessage$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType<MessageRequested>(MessageActionTypes.MessageRequested),
            mergeMap((action) => this.converseService.getMessage( action[0].message_id )),
            map(m => m.model),
            withLatestFrom(  this.store.pipe(select(selectVisitorById( m.visitor_id ) ))),
            tap( ([message,visitor]) => {
                if (visitor == null) new VisitorRequested(message.visitor_id);
            }),
            map( ([message, visitor]) => {
                return new MessageLoaded({message});
            } )
        );
```

```
export class Message {
    id: number;
    message: string;
    visitor_id: number;
    is_from_visitor: boolean;
    created_at: string;
}

export class MessageResponse extends Response {
  model: Message
}

export class Response{
  message:String;
  didError: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
}
```

Code looks alright, except that `withLatestFrom` does not accept inputs, so I can't pass the `m.visitor_id` variable, and now I have to think of another approach. I tried using `forkJoin` and `concatMap`, but didnt make it.

What would be right operators to utilize in the scenario?

## Update #1

This is what finally worked with the help of all the answers:

```
    @Effect()
    loadMessage$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType<MessageRequested>(MessageActionTypes.MessageRequested),
            mergeMap((action) => this.converseService.getMessage( action.message_id )),
            map(m => m.model),
            concatMap(message =>
                of(message).pipe(
                  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectVisitorById(message.visitor_id))))
                )
            ),            
            tap( ([message,visitor]) => {
                if (!(visitor)) this.store.dispatch(new VisitorRequested(message.visitor_id));
            }),
            map( ([message, visitor]) => {
                return new MessageLoaded({message});
            } )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tap` does not return a value, it's just a void.
Instead, return an array of actions depending on the condition:

```
 switchMap(([message,visitor]) => {
    if (visitor == null) return [new VisitorRequested(message.visitor_id), new MessageLoaded({message})];
    return [new MessageLoaded({message})]
 })
```

Imho, the more correct answer would be to have 2 effects:

1) listen to `MessageActionTypes.MessageRequested` and dispatch `MessageLoaded`
2) listen to  `MessageActionTypes.MessageRequested` and dispatch `VisitorRequested` if it isn't in the store. Or even, put the logic of `VisitorRequested` in this effect.

Comment: but how to pass the m.visitor_id to the withLatestFrom, since it doesn’t accept any inputs

Comment: see https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects for an example

Comment: you pointed out the right answer in the article, ill update the question with what finally worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass down some data from the store along with data from an action, you can pass a map function to `withLatestFrom()`:

```
someEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(SOME_ACTION),
            withLatestFrom(this.store.select(yourFeature), (action, data) => ({ dataFromStore: data, payload: action.payload })),
            switchMap(props => {
                // do something fun
            })  
        )
    );
```

As stated in https://ngrx.io/guide/effects, it is also recommended to wrap withLatestFrom in a flattening operator, because withLatestFrom will listen through the `select()` right away regardless of the action coming in.

```
concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
     withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(yourFeature)))
))
```

Comment: but how to combine the data from the action, along with the data from the store, along the data from API as in the example